# Searching for a similar tex font

Tags: fonts

I'm trying to find out what font this book is written with and which similar tex font I could use. Any idea?

[image]

Comment: I'd say this is some kind of Garamond

Comment: Yes, but... I spent half a night to identify which Garamond it is without results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it could be [Monotype Garamond](https://www.fonts.com/font/monotype/monotype-garamond):
[image: Monotype Garamond]
Look for example at the slope of the aperture in the lowercase “a”, and the tail’s angle in uppercase “Q”. The weight is also a good match, I think.

[EB Garamond](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/ebgaramond/) is available on CTAN (`\usepackage{ebgaramond}`) and it’s quite close. Another option would be [URW Garamond](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/urw-garamond) (or, better, the package [`garamondx`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/garamondx) for small caps and old-style numerals), but in my opinion it’s less similar to Monotype than EB (especially in the italics).

EB Garamond:[image: EB Garamond]

URW Garamond:[image: URW Garamond]

Comment: It's Monotype Garamond. That's why I didn't find it on my font website.

Comment: EB Garamond doesn't look like Monotype Garamond. Any idea where to buy this one?

Comment: I found this: https://www.fonthaus.com/fonts/monotypeimaging/Monotype-Garamond/MI14706916. Individual styles are $35.00, full family $188.00.